# Maximum number of EBS volumes on an Ubuntu Server EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon documentation says that the number of EBS volumes that can be attached to a Linux EC2 instance is essentially unlimited, but it seems the number of potential available device names is limited to:

/dev/sd[f-p][1-6]

Which is 11 * 6 = 66 volumes

What I want to do is have an EC2 instance that has thousands of EBS volumes attached, and want to know if this is possible?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Since EBS volumes are network attached storage, you will likely saturate the network interface before you can effectively use all those volumes. 4-8 volumes is more of a practical limit if you want to maximize I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You can not attach multiple EBS volumes to an single EC2Instance .But you can attach multiple volumes to an ec2instance .